# cmake and enabling systemd service

Tags: cmake, systemd

I am installing a systemd service in my cmake file:

```
install(FILES test.service DESTINATION /lib/systemd/system)
```

My question is how do I then enable the service automatically? i.e.
systemctl enable test
I could run a script to do it as part of the install but that doesn't seem right.

Comment: I think this is more of a job for the final package / installer. If, for example, you're using CPack and the Debian generator, you can add a `postinst` script to `CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_CONTROL_EXTRA` that will run when your Debian package is installed. This can contain `systemctl enable test` or whatever else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alex Reinking said CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_CONTROL_EXTRA was what I needed. I also needed to run configure_file before setting CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_CONTROL_EXTRA